# Writing to a new line in a .csv file without overwriting the first line

Tags: java, file, io, java-io, filewriter

I'm trying to make it so whenever a user inputs a name and pass it will write that information(in the format of name,pass) to a .csv file specified by the location. However whenever I run the program, it keeps overwriting the first line. I tried adding `"\n"` and `out.newLine();` but for some reason it doesn't write to the next line. I have no idea why it does this so I was hoping if someone knows why.

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String location = "my location to the file (.csv)";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Pass: ");
        String pass = sc.next();
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(location));
        out.write(name + "," + pass + "\n");
        out.newLine();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Currently in the file I have this:

> test, one

and when I ran the program:

```
name: one
pass: two
```

exited the program and checked the file and the first line was replaced with one,two instead of making it like this:

```
test, one
one, two
```

Thank you for those who help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second constructor of [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

> **FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)**
>
> **fileName** - String The system-dependent filename.
>   **append** - boolean if true, then data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(location, true));
```

Comment: Thank you Eng Fouad :). Didn't know about the true part :O.

Comment: @Sc4r You are welcome. It's always a good idea to read JavaDocs ;)